# How can I scale a velocity value from native units (ticks per 100ms) to meters per second?

Tags: java, scalar, converters

I'm trying to convert the native units on Talon SRX Mag/Quad encoders to meters per second to find the max velocity and acceleration of my tank drive robot. This is how I calculated the scalar to convert native to meters per second, but when I tested with this, the values seemed pretty low (.6 m/s, or 1.3mph, which I'm fairly sure is slower than the bot is):

```
/**
 * Drive values
 */
public static final double
    GEAR_RATIO         = 4.67,
    CTRE_TICKS         = 4096,
    CTRE_TICKS_PER_REV = CTRE_TICKS * GEAR_RATIO, // wheel revs per revolution * ticks per revolution
    WHEEL_DIAMETER     = 6, // inches
    CIRCUMFERENCE      = WHEEL_DIAMETER * Math.PI,
    INCHES_PER_TICK    = CIRCUMFERENCE / CTRE_TICKS_PER_REV, // inches per rev divided by ticks per rev
    IPDS_TO_MPH        = .568, // convert inches per decisecond to miles per hour
    IPDS_TO_MEPS       = .254, // this is a conspiracy bigger than all of us
    CTRE_NATIVE_TO_MPH = INCHES_PER_TICK * IPDS_TO_MPH,
    CTRE_NATIVE_TO_MPS = INCHES_PER_TICK * IPDS_TO_MEPS;
```

The encoder itself records 4096 ticks per turn of the motor shaft, which then goes through a 4.67:1 gearbox (4.67 motor revs per wheel rev), and to 6-inch wheels.
To find the converted velocity, I report the encoder's velocity times Constants.CTRE_NATIVE_TO_MPS.

Answer (score -1):

My encoders are different from yours but the formulas should be the same.

I did a video on how to use wheel encoders and calculate the robot linear and angular speeds. (https://youtu.be/ktZTN5aUYPY)

If you follow the video you will see that in the project doc folder, there is a ppt file with all the formulas. (https://github.com/gusbots/mark01/tree/v3.1/doc)

Here is a snapshot of it:

[image]

where vr and vl are the angular velocities in rad/s, R is the radius of the wheel and L is the distance between the wheels.